# File.GetAttributes syntax

Tags: .net, file-io

I am trying to debug an application I'm not familiar with.

Somewhere in the code, I see this :

```
File.GetAttributes(FileName) _
    .Equals(FileAttributes.Archive | FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
```

What exactly does the `FileAttributes.Archive | FileAttributes.ReadOnly` (with a single pipe) tests ? I guessed that it was to see if the file was either archived or readonly, but the file is archived, and the test returns false.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is just flat-out wrong.  Whoever wrote it messed around until they got it working.  FileAttributes is an Enum type that has the [Flags] attribute.  Which means that any *combination* of flags can be set.  Which is what the OR operator does, it combines both the Archive and the ReadOnly attributes.

Which works by accident, a file often has the Archive attribute turned on.  The code will fail miserably once the user backs-up the file.  That turns off the Archive attribute and the Equals() method no longer works, even though the file is still ReadOnly.

You must fix this bug.  Make it look like this instead:

```
If (File.GetAttributes(FileName) And FileAttributes.ReadOnly) = FileAttributes.ReadOnly Then
   '' It is read-only
   ''...
End If
```

Comment: "That code is just flat-out wrong" - to say it's "wrong" requires you to know what was intended.  I agree the test doesn't make much sense, but the intention might have been something other than testing for a ReadOnly file.

Comment: No, this is not subtle.  It is flat-out wrong.  Induced by thinking that Equals() was appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. I can't modify this as I don't (yet) have access to the SCM, but I will point out the problem to the developers.

Answer (score 2):

`FileAttributes.Archive | FileAttributes.ReadOnly` means to combine (bitwise OR) both values. Call to `Equal()` means comparing for equality. Hence it will yield `true` if and only if the file has *both* Archive *and* Read-only bits set.

Answer (score 2):

```
 File.GetAttributes(FileName) _
    .Equals(FileAttributes.Archive | FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
```

will only return true if:

- Both the Archive and ReadOnly bits are set,

and

- None of the other FileAttributes bits (e.g. Hidden, System, Compressed, ...) is set.

This doesn't seem a very useful test at first glance - why would one want to exclude compressed files?